# Can I run a sink drain through the wall to connect back where it was before relocation?

Tags: plumbing

I want to know if it is an option to run the drain along and within the wall where the new sink sits and back to where the old sink drain is.

Another option would be to connect to the drain of the sink (*shown in   the left side of the image*) that is in the kitchen adjacent to the same wall where the new sink is installed.

The shower heads will be located in the corner.

Here is the current layout.

[image]

and here is the new layout.

[image]

Comment: Are you opening up the walls to get the vent for the new location within 5' of the farthest drain? Otherwise your drains will be noisy.Let alone it will not meet code if you don't.

Comment: You don't show where the supply & waste plumbing for the new tub is, but I suspect it'll have to come around the corner so the tub & sink plumbing are in the same wall. You could run the sink drain to the tub drain, then down from there. I _think_ a combined vent to be tied into an existing vent, somewhere should take care of it for you, but wait for the plumbers/code guys to give it a say so.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as you can maintain 1/4" per foot of slope between your new location and old one.

Comment: :-))  
Am I going to have enough room in the wall to go around the piping for the shower ? Please see my other related question  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/198582/do-i-need-to-relocate-the-shower-and-open-the-floor-again-if-i-rotate-by-basemen

Comment: That's really an on site kind of question unless we have a lot more info. I'm not a plumber at all, so maybe others here could weigh in.  If not, with my pinky finger in the corner of my mouth I say "release the professional plumbers", and the frau says: "RELEASE THE PROFESSIONAL PLUMBERS"

Comment: :)) I am being told that there is a vent in the wall that was removed in the second picture next to the toilet. The question is ..can I reroute that vent for its bottom part and move it into the exterior wall?